# Google App for Business Gmail vs Classic Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

We are in transition to move on to Google Apps. I and also my coworkers have been using Gmail for quite some time now. We imported email our company mail accounts in our Gmail and things work smoothly.

I created standard account for Google Apps for Business to give it a try before migrating to Premier Edition. But there are couple of thing bothering me. They did such a good work with classic Gmail. Especially with contact management and GUI is also very comfortable to work with. But in Google Apps for Business Gmail frontend is like Gmail 2 years ago. Is there any good reason for this? Will this stay this way? Because its really unorthodox to have classic Gmail for free with all these features and when you pay you are transported back to the past. I haven't tried Premier Edition but I guess it has the same user interface. Do any of you have insight in this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Gmail is updated quite regularly (mine just had the Priority Inbox feature added, and I can remember a few layout changes this year and things like labels being updated, my calendar's also been updated a few times) but it is always a bit behind the free Gmail.

I think that you may be looking at this the wrong way round. The paid for Google Apps version is the tried and tested rock-solid stable and safe GMail, whereas the free GMail is the experimental one. Think of the free users as experimental guinea pigs for your paid account, they find the problems with new features and designs, which are then either fixed or removed before they make it to the paid Gmail.

There are ways to make sure that your domain is one of the first to get any changes rolled out to it, firstly make sure that you're set to the English US as your domain's default language as all changes are rolled out to that language first, secondly sign up for your domain on the form at http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html to volunteer for some experimental changes to be tried on your domain.